# Perl unable to write file on server

Tags: perl, web, iis-7

I have a file *in.txt* with some text.
I am using IIS 7 local server on Windows. and *isapiModule* is working fine for perl.
When I run this perl code via browser it is printing to browser just print line (not data) but not writing to file *out.txt* and just opening the empty file *out.txt*  (i.e. unable to write via browser).
My wwwroot folder has full control access for all users.

**html code:**

```
<html>
<body>

<form name="form1" action="perl.pl" method="post"
enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

**perl.pl:**

```
open(file,"<in.txt");
@x=<file>;
open(OUT,">out.txt");
print"print to browser...";
print OUT"@x\n";#for printing to file
close file;
close OUT;
```

What may be the reason and solution.

**UPDATE:** program is writing when manually run via command drive.

Comment: `use strict; use warnings;` and test if the open failed.

Comment: @M42 Error: "Script failed to send data."

Comment: Hi, any update? I'm facing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict; 


my $in = 'in.txt';
open my $file, '<', $in or die "Can't open $in\n";

my $outfile = 'out.txt';
open my $outprint, '>', $outfile or die "Can't write to $outfile\n";


print "print to browser…\n";
while (<$file>) { 
    chomp;
    print $outprint "$_\n"; 
}
```

Comment: Hi, it's working fine in command line but it's error in IIS: "Can't open in.txt". Any solution? Thanks.